# How to "Keyboard Focus" on Web Page just opened by ShellExecute?

Tags: vba, google-chrome, outlook

I open all hyperlinks in an Outlook email using `ShellExecute`.

I want to save all opened web pages (my default browser is Chrome).

I tried `SendKeys`. I suspect that I need to put some codes after `ShellExecute` and before `SendKeys` so that it will recognize the opened web pages as "active." In other words, I would like to set keyboard focus on the Chrome web page that was opened.

```vb
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute _
  Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
  ByVal hWnd As Long, _
  ByVal Operation As String, _
  ByVal Filename As String, _
  Optional ByVal Parameters As String, _
  Optional ByVal Directory As String, _
  Optional ByVal WindowStyle As Long = vbMinimizedFocus _
  ) As Long

Sub OpenLinksMessage()
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Reg1 As RegExp
    Dim M1 As MatchCollection
    Dim M As Match
    Dim strURL As String
    Dim lSuccess As Long
 
    Set olMail = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection(1)

    Set Reg1 = New RegExp

    With Reg1
        .Pattern = "(https?[:]//([0-9a-z=\?:/\.&-^!#$%;_])*)"
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
    End With

    If Reg1.Test(olMail.Body) Then

        Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(olMail.Body)
        For Each M In M1
            strURL = M.SubMatches(0)
            Debug.Print strURL
            If InStr(strURL, "unsubscribe") Then GoTo NextURL
            If Right(strURL, 1) = ">" Then strURL = Left(strURL, Len(strURL) - 1)

            lSuccess = ShellExecute(0, "Open", strURL)
            DoEvents

            'This is where I think I need codes

            SendKeys ("^S"), True
            SendKeys ("name"), True
            SendKeys "{Enter}", True

NextURL:
  
        Next
    End If

    Set Reg1 = Nothing
End Sub
```

After figuring out this, I will adjust the codes to do it in a loop to open and save 100+ links.

Comment: I have this code using IE Object , but i think thats not wat you want , right ? 
And what exactly do you want to save with CTRL+S ? We can do better then Send keys for you if u tell the purpose...

Comment: Ty for your response. Unfortunately, I cannot use the internet explorer (IE) - the hyperlink, I tried to open, supported by only Chrome. To clarify, what I really need is to set keyboard focus on the Chrome web page that I opened.

Answer (score 0):

I have commented that we can use IE object , and Do better ways to automate that process

but answering your question you can try

```
Dim i As Integer

SendKeys ("^S"), True
On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To 100
    VBA.AppActivate ("Save As")
Next i
On Error GoTo 0
SendKeys ("name"), True
SendKeys "{Enter}", True
```

Comment: I added your code and got "Compile error - Expected:expression"